# Table with relationship to self

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a client table where some cases an individual client has a relationship to another client that we want to set as the parent and in those cases it could be multiple clients to one parent.

This would apply to maybe 10 to 20 percent of the records and the rest would have zero related. I am thinking a child table with the Client Id and parent Id.

Is that the normal way this type of relationship is handled?

This is a legacy database and generally they have added a column in these cases but I figure its not to late to do it correctly.

Comment: This feature is called: hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each client can only have one parent then the following is fine:-

```
ID ClientInfo1 ClientInfo2 ParentID

Where ParentID = ID of the parent record.
```

Or if can have multiple parents then yes you want another table

```
ClientID ParentID
```

This way you can have multiple parents for each client

You need to look up 1 to many and many to many relationships and decide which is correct.

Comment: Initially I was thinking of that but in most cases there is no relationship so the parentID would be null for 80 to 90%

Comment: that isnt a problem - you would find the parent using JOIN - you can join a table on itself and it wont care about Nulls assuming your query is written correctly. For the second option of multiples you only have entries where there is a relationship so you wont have any nulls in there.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afcd0/7 <- hopefully will show you what I mean for the 1 to many